# Gunicorn & django: connect() to unix:/home/ubuntu/webapps/kenyabuzz/kb.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

Setting up a django site with gunicorn & nginx I can run it with `gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 myproject.wsgi:application` however gunicorn instance with nginx fails with an error can't connect to sock file (and doesn't create it also).

The error log is:

```
2017/02/01 11:43:47 [crit] 30225#30225: *9 connect() to unix:/home/ubuntu/webapps/kenyabuzz/kb.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 197.232.12.165, server: kenyabuzz.nation.news, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/ubuntu/webapps/kenyabuzz/kb.sock:/", host: "kenyabuzz.nation.news"
```

relevant settings are `/etc/init/gunicorn.conf`

```
description "Gunicorn application server handling all projects"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
setuid user
setgid www-data
chdir /home/ubuntu/webapps/kenyabuzz

exec /home/ubuntu/webapps/djangoenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/ubuntu/webapps/kenyabuzz/kb.sock kb.wsgi:application
```

and `/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=ubuntu
Group=nginx
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/webapps/kenyabuzz
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/webapps/djangoenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/ubuntu/webapps/kenyabuzz/kb.sock kb.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

nginx conf file

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name kenyabuzz.nation.news;

    # Django media
    location /media  {
        alias /home/ubuntu/webapps/kenyabuzz/kb/media;  # your Django project's media files - amend as required
    }

    location /static {
        alias /home/ubuntu/webapps/kenyabuzz/kb/static; # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    }

    location /favicon.ico {
        alias /home/ubuntu/webapps/kenyabuzz/kb/static/kb/favicon.ico; # favicon
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/webapps/kenyabuzz/kb.sock;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Gunicorn status

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-17-122:~$ sudo systemctl status gunicorn
● gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2017-02-01 11:26:01 UTC; 21h ago
  Process: 30211 ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/webapps/djangoenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home
 Main PID: 30211 (code=exited, status=216/GROUP)

Feb 01 11:26:01 ip-172-31-17-122 systemd[1]: Started gunicorn daemon.
Feb 01 11:26:01 ip-172-31-17-122 systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Main process exited, code=exited, sta
Feb 01 11:26:01 ip-172-31-17-122 systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Unit entered failed state.
Feb 01 11:26:01 ip-172-31-17-122 systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
lines 1-10/10 (END)
```

Comment: Can you post your nginx config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with the `group` set it to `www-data` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration looks good to me. Make sure the gunicorn service is actually running and has permissions to write the socket file.

Update: Have a close look at the status of the service, the service is **not** running.

Try running the command in a shell and see if there is any conclusive output.

Comment: daemon is running I've included the status also

Comment: look at this `upstream: "http://unix:/home/ubuntu/webapps/kenyabuzz/kb.sock:/"` the sock file has `:\` at the end in the error log